# I am trying to select a checkbox in selenium but I am unable to, Why?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I have a check box in my code which I am trying to select. I have also tried the absolute xpath but it does not get selected.
The code is pasted below. Can someone please help me with it?

```
<label for="brandFilter*">ALL</label>
<div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxHover dijitHover dijitCheckBoxFocused dijitCheckBoxHoverFocused dijitHoverFocused dijitFocused" role="presentation" widgetid="brandFilter1">
<input id="brandFilter1" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" type="checkbox" dojoattachevent="onclick:_onClick" dojoattachpoint="focusNode" name="brandFilter" style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="0" aria-pressed="false"/>
</div>
<label class="dijitFocusedLabel" for="brandFilter1">Power Systems</label
```

The error that I get is:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not
>   clickable at point (465, 669).

Other element would receive the click:

```
<div id="results-loading" class="dealreg-load" style="filter:alpha(opacity=90); opacity:0.9;">...</div>
```

Comment: Are you using chrome Driver ?

Comment: can you please post your java code as well ?

Comment: The exception you are getting is stating that another element is obscuring the checkbox you want to click. You may need a wait to allow a modal, alert or loading throbber to disappear before clicking, or for a page to complete rendering.

Comment: Other things that may cause this problem would be floating headers/footers. In which case you would need to scroll the element into view.

Comment: @TAsk- yes I am using chrome driver

Comment: I just read the full exception and noticed that the element that would is in the way has the id="results-loading". I assume this is a loading progress bar or similar. You need to wait for this item to go before you can click the desired checkbox.

Comment: It worked now.. @Lensman thanks applying more wait worked..!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a loading indicator that is on top of the desired element when you search for it. Wait for your desired *element to become clickable*:

```
WebDriverWait wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement brandFilter = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.ID("brandFilter1")));
brandFilter.click();
```

Or, wait for the loading indicator to disappear:

```
WebDriverWait wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ID("results-loading")));

WebElement brandFilter = driver.findElement(By.ID("brandFilter1"));
brandFilter.click();
```

---

What can also help:

- maximizing the browser window:

  ```
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  ```
- scrolling into view of the element:

  ```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", brandFilter);
  ```